# Why the condition where not readable in the query repository?

Tags: laravel, repository, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I get repository tutorial from here :

https://github.com/rinvex/repository

And I try make code like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Favorite;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container;
use Rinvex\Repository\Repositories\EloquentRepository;
use DB;
Use Log;

class FavoriteRepository extends EloquentRepository
{
    // Instantiate repository object with required data
    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->setContainer($container)
             ->setModel(Favorite::class)
             ->setRepositoryId('rinvex.repository.uniqueid');
    }

    public function getFavoriteStore($user_id, $id_store)
    {
        DB::enableQueryLog();

        $query = Self::where('favoritable_id', $id_store)
                         ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                         ->first();
                         
        $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
        foreach($queries as $i=>$query)
        {
            Log::debug("Query $i: " . json_encode($query));
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

I debug the query and the result is like this :

> array:3 [▼
>
> "query" => "select * from `favorites` limit 1"
>
> "bindings" => []
>
> "time" => 1.28
>
> ]

It looks, there are no conditions where

Why did it happen?

Comment: try `static::` instead of `Self::`

Comment: @zgabievi, It does not work

Comment: @mosestoh Have you used `$this->where('favoritable_id', $id_store)->where('user_id', $user_id) ->first();` ?? It should work for you.